Issue with Custom Plugin in Ktor Multimodule Project (No value present error)
I'm currently learning backend development with Ktor and exploring a multimodule project setup similar to what I've done in Android development. Note: When I refer to "modules," I'm talking about actual project modules (like in Android), not the Ktor-specific module terminology.
What I Want to Achieve:
I want to apply Clean Architecture principles by separating my Ktor project into multiple modules, such as data, domain, presentation, etc. To make the build setup cleaner, I created a build-logic module to store Kotlin convention plugins that I can reuse across my project modules.
Current Setup:
I added a build-logic module to store my custom plugins.
In my settings.gradle.kts, I included the build-logic module with the following:
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("build-logic")
}

In the build-logic module, I created a class KtorLibraryConventionPlugin representing a plugin convention for Ktor libraries.
My build-logic/build.gradle.kts looks like this:
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register("ktorLibrary") {
            id = "sermilion.ktor.library"
            implementationClass = "KtorLibraryConventionPlugin"
        }
    }
}

In the libs.versions.toml, I defined the plugin:
sermilion-ktor-library = { id = "sermilion.ktor.library", version = "unspecified" }

I'm applying the plugin in my main module's build.gradle.kts like this:
alias(libs.plugins.sermilion.ktor.library)

Problem:
When I try to build the project, I encounter the following error:
Build file 'C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\ProjectName\build.gradle.kts' line: 4
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'sermilion.ktor.library', version: 'unspecified'] 
> Failed to apply plugin 'sermilion.ktor.library'.
   > No value present

I've been stuck on this for a few hours and can’t figure out what’s wrong.
Questions:
Is a multimodule setup (with actual separate modules like data, domain, etc.) a valid approach in Ktor projects? I want to ensure this makes sense before diving deeper.
What am I missing in my custom plugin setup that's causing the No value present error? I suspect it might have to do with how I'm registering the plugin or referencing it in the libs.versions.toml.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Property implementationClass must be a fully qualified class-name:
id = "sermilion.ktor.library"
displayName = "..."
description = "..."
implementationClass = "sermilion.ktor.library.KtorLibraryConventionPlugin"

See https://github.com/uteke/gradle-kotlin-convention-plugins.

This might be a better example, using the default directory buildSrc.
This directory can be used for plugins, without having to include anything.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:convention_plugins
